# Schema mutation for deleteMany({})

Tags: prisma

I have this simple resolver:

```
  removeAllMovies: () => {
    return prisma.movie.deleteMany({});
  },
```

When I run my apollo client I get an error:

> Mutation.removeAllMovies defined in resolvers, but not in schema

So I want to add the mutation to the schema but I can't find the correct syntax. I want to remove all the movies, not based on a id or a filter:

```
type Mutation {
  removeAllMovies()
}
```

This shows an error while starting the Apollo server:

> Syntax Error: Expected Name, found ")".

What's the correct schema syntax for a `deleteMany({})` resolver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
type BatchPayload {
  count: Int!
}

type Mutation {
  removeAllMovies: BatchPayload
}
```

And the resolver is correct so no changes there.

Comment: Could you explain how it works or reference a documentation? What's BatchPayload?

Comment: https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#deletemany

Comment: Okay I got it :). The `BatchPayload` is the return value of how many records are deleted. Also I was messing around in the sandbox because I did `removeAllMovies()` but I didn't specify any arguments in the schema. `mutation {removeAllMovies {count}}` does the trick in the sandbox.